# Recreating an app to publish as an update on playstore

Tags: android, version-control, version

I know it's foolish. I've developed an app and uploaded to play store. It gained users in thousands now but accidentally I've deleted the local project folder from my computer. Is it possible to recreate the project and publish it as an update. I've the `.jks` file with me which was created while signing the app.

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance (:

Comment: You have to keep same package name in your code

Comment: Thanks for the quick response have you done similar before? @VivekMishra

Comment: Do you have existing code with you or not?

Comment: No I lost the whole project. But as the users are in thousands it worths rewriting the code @VivekMishra

Comment: Well I recreated an eclipse project to Android Studio. So I think it should work

Comment: Okay I'll try it. Thanks (:

Comment: Here, http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename , are the reasons why you have to mantain the same package name in your code

Comment: You have probably figured it out by now, but use something like bitbucket or girhub :)

Comment: @RaymonddelaCroix Yeah I do it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to publishing updated your old app on play store you need only below things for it.

**-same keystore as you created before while signing the app**

**-package name should be same.**

That's it..!

Answer (score 1):

If you keep the same package name, have the signing certificate and can handle persistent data (i.e. your SQLite/SharedPreferences storage) migration, the answer is yes.

Answer (score 1):

Yah it is possible just maintain the same package name and incremented Version Code and Version Name